# Can you figure out this APCS project?

Tags: java

write a program to make a magic square of numbers. A Magic Square is a matrix of numbers. Every column, every row, and every diagonal add up to the same value. Read in matrix values and determine if the sum of all rows, columns, and diagonals is the same. If all have the same sum, print out that the matrix is a magic square. Otherwise, print that the matrix is not a magic square.

So I'm really struggling with this problem. I'm not even sure how to start and I would really appreciate If any of you would show me how to complete this project. I know it might this might be vexing for you, but please show mercy to a new coder. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class MagicSquare1
{
    private int[][] mat;

    //size the matrix and load in the numbers into the matrix
    //write all nested loop code here in the constructor
    public MagicSquare1(int size, String numbers)
    {
        size = 0;
        numbers = "";


    }

    public boolean isMagicSquare()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public int sumRow( int r )
    {

        return 0;
    }

    public int sumCol( int c )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public int sumDownDiag()
    {
        return 0; 
    }

    public int sumUpDiag()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String output="";
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately you've provided a (practically) empty starting class. Please show what you have attempted already and explain what went wrong. A [mcve] demonstrating the exact problem is the best way to get help here at SO.

Comment: I would start by breaking the overall problem down into smaller problems.

1. How to read in the matrix values.
2. How to calculate the sum of values for a row in the matrix.
3. How to calculate the sum of values for a column.
4. How to calculate the sum of values for a diagonal.
5. How to combine all the above to produce the required output.